# File content into unix variable with newlines

Tags: bash, unix

I have a text file test.txt with the following content:

```
text1
text2
```

And I want to assign the content of the file to a UNIX variable, but when I do this:

```
testvar=$(cat test.txt)
echo $testvar
```

the result is:

```
text1 text2
```

instead of

```
text1
text2
```

Can someone suggest me a solution for this?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

The assignment does *not* remove the newline characters, it's actually the `echo` doing this. You need simply put quotes around the string to maintain those newlines:

```
echo "$testvar"
```

This will give the result you want. See the following transcript for a demo:

```
pax> cat num1.txt ; x=$(cat num1.txt)
line 1
line 2

pax> echo $x ; echo '===' ; echo "$x"
line 1 line 2
===
line 1
line 2
```

---

The *reason* why newlines are replaced with spaces is not *entirely* to do with the `echo` command, rather it's a combination of things.

When given a command line, `bash` splits it into words according to the documentation for the `IFS` variable:

> **IFS:** The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion ... the default value is `<space><tab><newline>`.

That specifies that, by default, any of those three characters can be used to split your command into individual words. After that, the word separators are gone, all you have left is a list of words.

Combine that with the `echo` documentation (a `bash` internal command), and you'll see why the spaces are output:

> **echo [-neE] [arg ...]:** Output the args, separated by spaces, followed by a newline.

When you use `echo "$x"`, it forces the entire `x` variable to be a *single* word according to `bash`, hence it's not split. You can see that with:

```
pax> function count {
...>    echo $#
...> }
pax> count 1 2 3
3
pax> count a b c d
4
pax> count $x
4
pax> count "$x"
1
```

Here, the `count` function simply prints out the number of arguments given. The `1 2 3` and `a b c d` variants show it in action.

Then we try it with the two variations on the `x` variable. The one *without* quotes shows that there are four words, `"test"`, `"1"`, `"test"` and `"2"`. Adding the quotes makes it *one* single word `"test 1\ntest 2"`.

Comment: Also worth noting: _Trailing_ newlines will be removed by the command substitution operator itself: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9FWPSM1Jyefi0udq6AoM68kTUG1WEFJJVFJwU6hJDW3QK@kooQrObEEzlHgSrJV0UAW0UTRmaSExFXX1dVV//8fAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 13):

This is due to [IFS (Internal Field Separator)](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~uwe/lehre/unixffb/quoting-guide.html#para:sh-ifs) variable which contains newline.

```
$ cat xx1
1
2

$ A=`cat xx1`
$ echo $A
1 2

$ echo "|$IFS|"
|       
|
```

**A workaround is to reset IFS to not contain the newline, temporarily**:

```
$ IFSBAK=$IFS
$ IFS=" "
$ A=`cat xx1` # Can use $() as well
$ echo $A
1
2
$ IFS=$IFSBAK
```

To REVERT this horrible change for IFS:

```
IFS=$IFSBAK
```

Comment: I have done this change but now my other things are not working please tell me to reset it back ?

Comment: If you don't need it to go to a variable, a direct one-liner: `echo "$(IFS=''; cat text.txt)"`

Answer (score 10):

Bash -ge 4 has the mapfile builtin to read lines from the standard input into an array variable.

```
help mapfile 

mapfile < file.txt lines
printf "%s" "${lines[@]}"

mapfile -t < file.txt lines    # strip trailing newlines
printf "%s\n" "${lines[@]}"
```

See also:

http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/commands/builtin/mapfile

Answer (score 9):

Your variable is set correctly by `testvar=$(cat test.txt)`. To display this variable which consist new line characters, simply add double quotes, e.g.

```
echo "$testvar"
```

Here is the full example:

```
$ printf "test1\ntest2" > test.txt
$ testvar=$(<test.txt)
$ grep testvar <(set)
testvar=$'test1\ntest2'
$ echo "$testvar"
text1
text2
$ printf "%b" "$testvar"
text1
text2
```

Answer (score 3):

Just if someone is interested in another option:

```
content=( $(cat test.txt) )

a=0
while [ $a -le ${#content[@]} ]
do
        echo ${content[$a]}
        a=$[a+1]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The `envdir` utility provides an easy way to do this.  `envdir` uses files to represent environment variables, with file names mapping to env var names, and file contents mapping to env var values.  If the file contents contain newlines, so will the env var.

See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/envdir