# Multi-line config variables in Heroku

Tags: configuration, heroku

I've have a Rails app that loads a number of RSA certificates before a transaction is made with Paypal. On my development machine, these certificates are read from files in the file system but because Heroku (which I'm using for delpoyment) is largely read-only, I can't upload these files so I'm guessing I'll have to read the certificates from config variables (see [Heroku Config Vars](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)).

Because the certificates consist of multiple lines of data, I'm not sure how to set them as variables or even if this is possible. Does anyone know how I could do this or be able to suggest an alternative approach?

Many thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 58):

I found that a easy way to add multi-line configs is to double quote them and then echo them from my local environment

```
heroku config:add EC2_PRIVATE_KEY="$EC2_PRIVATE_KEY"
```

Comment: This worked great for me. This answer was helpful to me as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789319/file-content-into-unix-variable-with-newlines You can just set the var by using cat on the file that stores the multi-line var.

Comment: `testvar=$(cat myfile.txt)`. Then `heroku config:add EC2_PRIVATE_KEY="$testvar"`

Comment: `heroku config:add EC2_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat privatekey.pem)"`

Comment: What happens when you echo the environment variable in the Heroku shell? Do you get spaces in the output, or actual newlines?

Answer (score 20):

If you want to set Heroku config values from your file contents, you can use the following shell trick:

```
$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY="$(cat path/to/secret.key)"
```

Multi-line values can be set directly by putting quotes around the value:

```
$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='first line
> second line'
```

If you're using Foreman to run locally (now `heroku local`), it doesn't support multi-line variables. You must use something to inject them into the environment first, such as [envdir](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/envdir):

```
$ envdir my-env-dir heroku local
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 5.0.0 app. I isolated it to being multi-line env var because changing it to a single line works. I get a psych parse error. Any thoughts on how to solve it?

Comment: Here's error. It's easy to create test case locally.
`/Users/hm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in 'parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 29 column 17 (Psych::SyntaxError)
 from /Users/hm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:377:in 'parse_stream'
 from /Users/hm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:325:in 'parse'
 from /Users/hm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:252:in 'load'
 from /Users/hm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:391:in 'secrets'`

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding to this...

I'm not a Ruby developer, but your stack trace indicates that Rails is trying to parse a YAML file. Nothing in this answer involves writing code or even having a YAML file anywhere, so I guess this is unrelated? I'd recommend having a look at rails/application.‌​rb to see what YAML file it's attempting to load.

Comment: Thanks for responding... I was setting some key in rails `secret.yml` file to the `env` var that contained a multi-line text from a `cert.pem` file. It turns out, the parser worked with other dummy test samples, but not the real `cert.pem` file (it broke the parser giving above error). The solution per Heroku was to create a `.profile` file that wrote the `env` to a file on disk which was read where needed in the app.

Answer (score 14):

Or you can just go to the *Settings* tab of the Heroku dashboard, open *Config Vars* and paste it in.

[image: Heroku Settings]

Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks. I pasted the private key without escaping any special chars and without doing "\n". Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Arik am facing the same problem - can you elaborate on what you mean by 'doing "\n"'? much appreicated

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I didn't add \n to the end of the lines

Answer (score 10):

We needed to do the same thing.

You can wrap the variable value in double quotes:

```
bobvila@bobuntu:~/svnroot/app/myapp$ heroku config:add woodchuck="How much wood
> could a woodchuck chuck
> if a woodchuck could chuck wood"
Adding config vars and restarting myapp... done, v25
woodchuck: How much wood
could a woodchuck chuck
if a woodchuck could chuck wood
bobvila@bobuntu:~/svnroot/app/myapp$ heroku config
=== Config Vars for myapp
woodchuck:                       How much wood
could a woodchuck chuck
if a woodchuck could chuck wood
bobvila@bobuntu:~/svnroot/app/myapp$
```

If you're using Foreman for localhost development, the .env file doesn't support multi-line variables so you'll need to export it to the shell before launching Foreman

Answer (score 8):

My answer comes a bit late but I had the same issue recently with multi-line env. variables on Heroku. 
My solution was to use `strict_encode64`:

```
encoded_secret = Base64.strict_encode64("my_multi_line_secret")
```

add the key:

```
$ heroku config:set SECRET_KEY='the encoded_secret string here'
```

In the code, you then decode it using `Base64.strict_decode64(ENV['SECRET_KEY'])`

Answer (score 7):

An example of how to deal with this problem using NodeJS. Sanitize the value by replacing `\\n` characters with `\n`:

```
process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

Taken from:
[Escaping issue with firebase privateKey as a Heroku config variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492587/escaping-issue-with-firebase-privatekey-as-a-heroku-config-variable)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very manual way of doing it, but what worked for me is to paste the private key into a text editor, find and replace `\n` with an actual line break and paste that as the value for the env var in Heroku.