# Where to store sensitive files for heroku platform?

Tags: git, security, heroku, deployment, storage

I have a private key file for a Firebase access which I don't want to store in GitHub repo obviously.

I am well aware [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379136/where-should-i-store-sensitive-files-on-heroku), but it's quite old and I don't see much of useful information there. Something might have changed since then hopefully?

So far I have a heroku branch with a commit that contains this private key and whenever I want to release new app version I am rebasing this branch onto master so the commit sits on top. However it's quite a hassle.

It would be probably enough to have some secure offsite storage that can be accessed through some regular credentials that can be stored in env variables. I want to avoid S3 as they require credit card just for a registration.

Any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with setting up [multi-line environment variables in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942600/multi-line-config-variables-in-heroku) (as suggested by the other question that you have linked to)?

If you're on Rails 5.1, there is now another option though - [encrypted secrets](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#encrypted-secrets). This allows you to commit an encrypted version of your private key file to version control, and just have the master key in Heroku. This appears to be based on the [sekrets gem](https://github.com/ahoward/sekrets), which could be an option for older Rails versions - but you'll want to read the docs and do some research there, if that's your preferred route.

Comment: Hm, for some strange reason I've totally missed that answer there. Thanks :) Well at least there will be a question with marker answer here.