# Error authenticating with JWT and googleapis (error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line)

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to connect to Google Analytics Reporting API v4 from my Node server (running as a Firebase Cloud Function). I want to authenticate using JWT, as per this example: http://nali.org/google-analytics-v4-api-node-js-starter-example/

However I am getting this error:

```
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Error (native)
    at Sign.sign (crypto.js:307:26)
    at Object.sign (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/jwa/index.js:76:45)
    at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
```

It seems like its trying to use a PEM file, but I just want to use the email and private key. Is this not possible? Is the example link I gave misleading?

Here is my code:

```
const email = functions.config().ga.email;
const privateKey = functions.config().ga.privatekey;
const scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];
const token = new googleapis.google.auth.JWT(email, null, privateKey, scope, null);

token.authorize( (error, tokens) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to GA:', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Authorized!', tokens);
  }
})
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rookie mistake: I was not escaping the `\n` in my privateKey string. `firebase functions:config:set` was converting `\n` to `\\n` Fixed code looks like:

```
const email = functions.config().ga.email;
const privateKey = _.replace(functions.config().ga.privatekey, /\\n/g, '\n');
const scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'];
const jsonWebToken = new googleapis.google.auth.JWT(email, null, privateKey, scope, null);

jsonWebToken.authorize( (error, tokens) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to GA:', error);
  } else {
    console.log('Authorized!', tokens);
  }
});
```

My actual problem was solved using this advice: [Escaping issue with firebase privateKey as a Heroku config variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492587/escaping-issue-with-firebase-privatekey-as-a-heroku-config-variable)