# Linking Google credentials to vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel, google-translation-api

I did my best to figure this one out by myself, but I'm totally missing something.

I'm using NextJS 12 and Google Cloud Translate's API to convert a word on a button. Locally it works fine, but once I try to deploy to vercel the permissions/keys gets messed up somewhere.

Locally I have my key.json, which I got from my service account. It's just in my project's root. I have my `.env.local` file that has references that key file. It looks like this

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=./<projectid&key>.json`

But when I try to translate, I get hit with an error.
`'Request failed with status code 500'`

My translate endpoint looks like this, which I pretty much copied from Google's small tutorial.

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();

  const projectId = <myprojectID>;
  const location = "global";

  async function translateText() {
    const request = {
      parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`,
      contents: [req.body.text],
      mimeType: "text/plain",
      sourceLanguageCode: "en",
      targetLanguageCode: "es",
    };

    const [response] = await translationClient.translateText(request);

    res.json(response.translations[0].translatedText);
  }
  translateText();
};
```

**Things I've tried**

1. Putting the JSON as one single environmental variable on vercel. So It was basically `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and the key.json file.
2. Tried putting it all in one line.
3. Tried taking the keys apart and putting it into a format like this:

```
GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE=service_account
GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID=project11111
GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID=11111111111111
etc
```

However I wasn't about to get this method working locally either.
4. Kept the `.env.local`'s path to key.json and just uploaded the key.json itself.

None of these worked and I'm pretty lost.

**Resources I've looked at**

1. https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/749#issuecomment-715009494
2. [Escaping issue with firebase privateKey as a Heroku config variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492587/escaping-issue-with-firebase-privatekey-as-a-heroku-config-variable/41044630#41044630)
3. https://daveteu.medium.com/call-google-cloud-function-from-vercel-serverless-hosting-1b1688bb462c

I've tried to apply these to my situation, but I couldn't figure it out. I'd really appreciate any help! Thank you so much.

Comment: have you added environment variables via project settings?
https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking around for a few days, I found a solution that worked.

I turned my `keys.json` into a base64 string using a similar command.
https://gist.github.com/tomi/0675e58919af4554b198cee3f84405e5

Then used the method found here.
https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/219

I put that base64 string into one line in my .env file to check and then did the same for Vercel environmental variables, and it worked.