# How to read a file into a variable and print it using that variable with exact format in shell

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I am trying to read to id_rsa file into a variable var( set var=`cat id_rsa`) in tcsh to provide input to a program. But when i echo the variable ( echo "$var")new lines are gone, its a one line file content. So how do i correctly store and print the variable?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789319/file-content-into-unix-variable-with-newlines

Comment: i am only using echo "$var" instead of echo $var

Comment: use `mapfile` instead.

Comment: the idea is to create a variable not array so that it can be passed as string like "$var" into program

Comment: In Bash it would work fine, but in csh ... :/

Comment: ya the question is for tcsh

Answer (score 1):

Don't use tcsh for this task, getting the output of a command into a variable in verbatim is unnecessarily difficult:

Some workarounds if you have to use tcsh are:

use redirection

```
% yourtool < id_rsa
```

Store the variable as base-16 (or something else) encoded stuff, so that it doesn't contain any newline characters that will get mangled by tcsh.

```
% set hex_contents = `<id_rsa xxd -l 16 -p`
```

Use a tempfile?

```
% set tempfile = `mktemp`
% program > tempfile
```

... later

```
% <tempfile other-program
```

I asked a similar question almost a year ago; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284220/tcsh-preserve-newlines-in-command-substitution

In case you're curious this is how you get the verbatim contents (credit Stéphane Chazelas).

```
set temp = "`(some command; echo .) | paste -d . - /dev/null`"
set var = ""
set nl = '\
'
foreach i ($temp:q)
  set var = $var:q$i:r:q$nl:q
end
set var = $var:r:q
```