# Why does the output of "ls -l" lose its newlines?

Tags: shell, ls

Why does my program ignore newlines?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Input dir path : "
read path

function lshead4()
{   

    for i in 1
    do
       ls -l $path | head -4

    done
}


echo $(lshead4)
```

Comment: `echo "$(lshead4)"` wirth double quotes, duplicate questiom

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File content into unix variable with newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789319/file-content-into-unix-variable-with-newlines)

Comment: Duplicate of [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)